# Modelagem Ruby on Rails

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, ruby, modelo-relacional

Pessoal tenho uma dúvida que eu não consigo enxergar qual a forma de resolver.

Eu tenho que realizar um programa de estoque em Ruby on Rails que contenham alguns equipamentos, esses os quais vão conter algumas avergiguações.

Por exemplo, vou ter computadores, impressoras,  telefones, dentre outros, cada um com sua tabela, pois contém elementos únicos cada um.

Então eu precisaria criar uma relação 1 pra N em Ruby on Rails, porque um computador pode ter N averiguações, porém uma impressora também pode conter N averiguações, o telefone, e todos os outros equipamentos.

Então a pergunta é, eu tenho que referenciar todas as tabelas na criação da averiguação, porém só preencher aquela qual eu iria usar? por exemplo:

Rails g scaffold Averiguacao descricao:string data:date computador:reference impressora:reference telefone:reference

Acho que não é assim porém não consigo entender qual seria a forma certa.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não criaria uma tabela para cada tipo de equipamento, e sim uma tabela de equipamentos.

Nesse caso, equipamento tem N averiguações normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que é na lógica que o Alex disse. Cada equipamento, possui várias averiguações, enquanto que várias averiguações pertence a um equipamento. Essa é uma relação um para vários (one_to_many).

Então mais ou menos seria

```
Rails g scaffold Equipment name:string description:string
```

E depois

```
Rails g scaffold Inquiry inquiry:text equipment:references
```

Feito isso, depois do rails db:migrate, basta especificar a relação entre esses dois models.

No model Equipment **has_many :inquiries**

No model Inquiry **belongs_to :equipment**

Provavelmente alguns ajustes deverão ser feitos na Views, desde que em Equipamentos será possível ver, e editar as averiguações. Se você estiver fazendo vários testes, lembre-se que é possível desfazer mudanças apenas trocando o "g" de generate para "d" de destroy.

```
Ex: rails d scaffold Equipment
```

Sei que isto parece simples, mas isso pode evitar bastante problemas. Principalmente quando estamos apenas testando.